# SUM rows only if it does not have one of the multivalued values

Tags: mysql, sql

Movies table:

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | title  | price |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | movie1 |    20 |
|  2 | movie2 |    15 |
|  3 | movie3 |    25 |
|  4 | movie4 |    10 |
+----+------+---------+
```

Categories table:

```
+-----+--------+
| idd | cat    |
+-----+--------+
|  1  | horror |
|  1  | comedy |
|  2  | drama  |
|  2  | sci-fi |
|  3  | action |
|  4  | sci-fi |
+-----+--------+
```

I want to make a query to sum the prices of all the movies except the ones that have 'sci-fi' as one of its categories.

I have tried this:

```
select count(distinct id) as no_of_movies, sum(price) as price
from (select distinct id,price
      from movies,categories
      where id=idd and not cat='sci-fi') as tt;
```

But it only works with the movies that have only one category, like 'movie4'.
It still sums 'movie2' as 'drama'.
So how can I also skip 'movie2' so that the output will be 45 instead of 60?

Comment: You need another table for the mapping of categories and movies.

Comment: Hi , I don't know much of SQL but what if you just sum up all at first and subtract out the one that have sci-fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select count(distinct id) as no_of_movies, sum(price) as price
from (select distinct id,price
      from movies,categories
      where id=idd and id not in (select idd 
                                  from categories 
                                  where cat = 'sci-fi')) as tt;
```